# Selenium test fails with Firefox when trying to log in

Tags: javascript, python, firefox, selenium, xpath

We created extensions for Chrome, Firefox and Safari and we want to test our extensions with Selenium. I created a test to log in to https://outlook.office365.com/owa/ and the test works with Chrome, but it fails with Firefox. Also with Chrome I had to inject the JavaScript code directly into the page, because when clicking on the sign in button with Selenium nothing happens. Do you know how I can log in to Office 365 with Firefox?

Here is my code:

```
import time
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

def login_to_office365(self, email, password, name):
    self.driver.maximize_window()
    self.driver.get(url='https://outlook.office365.com/owa/')
    self.assertEqual(first="Sign in to Office 365", second=self.driver.title)
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath="//form[@id='credentials']//input[@name='login']").send_keys(email)
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath="//form[@id='credentials']//input[@name='passwd']").send_keys(password)
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath="//span[@id='cred_sign_in_button'][text()='Sign in']").click() # Nothing happens from this click.
    self.driver.execute_script("Post.SubmitCreds();") # Works only with Chrome.
    WebDriverWait(driver=self.driver, timeout=30).until(expected_conditions.title_is("{} - Outlook Web App".format(name)))
    self.assertEqual(first="{} - Outlook Web App".format(name), second=self.driver.title)
```

The exception is a timeout exception when waiting for the title to change.

Comment: What version of selenium and ff you are using?

Comment: In addition, how does it fail?

Comment: @Saifur We use Selenium 2.45.0 and Firefox 36.0.1.

Comment: @alecxe as I said, there is a timeout exception when waiting for the title to change.

Comment: I think your Button click XPath is wrong, try "//*[@id='cred_sign_in_button']"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submit the form in a traditional way using [`submit()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.submit):

```
username_element = driver.find_element_by_id('username')
username_element.send_keys(email)

password_element = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
password_element.send_keys(password)

password_element.submit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Following would work in c# *(python one is equivalent)

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).sendKeys(email);
driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).sendKeys(password).submit();
```

Comment: Can you write it in Python?

Comment: @Uri `driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(password).submit()`.

Comment: @alecxe I got this exception: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'submit'` with Chrome and Firefox. I also tried `send_keys(password + "\n")` and it didn't work (the same timeout exception).

Comment: plus one for the initial idea about submit. Thanks!